# Error al hacer Left Join. El identificador formado por varias partes... no se pudo enlazar

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Lo primero explicaros lo que trato de hacer para que entendais mi problema.
Estoy desarrollando una plataforma web basada en PHP para realizar el mantenimiento de los distintos tipos de equipamiento que puede haber en una empesa (Altas, bajas y modificacion de los mismos)

Mi problema es que tengo en una tabla los datos de SIM, en otra los datos de los telefonos y por ultimo los tipos de telefono. Las tablas de telefono y SIM se relacionan por el idSIM. Como hay telefonos que no tienen ninguna SIM asignada, quiero mostrarlos en el listado de telefonos, pero con la SQL actual no salen (ya que una condicion es que coincida el idSIM)
SQL actual:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento,
    Equipamiento_TipoTelefono,
    SIM_Equipamiento 
WHERE 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.activo = 1 
    AND 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.tipoTelefono = Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.idTipo 
    AND 
    Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.descripcion='Empleados' 
    AND 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.idSIM = SIM_Equipamiento.idSIM  
ORDER BY 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.idTelefonia";
```

Estoy intentando hacer un left join para que muestre los telefonos que no tienen SIM, pero me da el error del titulo

SQL con Left Join:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento,
    Equipamiento_TipoTelefono
LEFT JOIN 
    SIM_Equipamiento 
ON 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.idSIM=SIM_Equipamiento.idSIM
WHERE 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.activo = 1 
    AND 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.tipoTelefono = Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.idTipo
    AND 
    Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.descripcion='Empleados';
```

[image: Estructura Base de datos]

Si necesitais mas informacion, datos o lo que sea, no dudeis en pedirmelo. 
Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Hola VVallejo, no uses el backtick para los codigos extensos (se usa para nombres de variables, clases, etc. ej: `function prueba()`). Para formatearlo, seleccionalo y pulsa `ctrl + k` o el icono `{}`. Un saludo

Comment: Comprendido, gracias por editarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que sería más correcto tener un inner join para la entidad que contiene el tipo de telefono, ya que cualquier telefono que este cargado deberá tener asignado un tipo de telefono.
Probalo de esta manera:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Telefonia_Equipamiento
        INNER JOIN  Equipamiento_TipoTelefono ON Telefonia_Equipamiento.tipoTelefono = Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.idTipo
        LEFT JOIN   SIM_Equipamiento ON Telefonia_Equipamiento.idSIM = SIM_Equipamiento.idSIM
WHERE   Telefonia_Equipamiento.activo = 1
        AND Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.descripcion = 'Empleados'
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Funciona!! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco de llevarte la tabla Equipamiento_TipoTelefono a otra left join, ya que no deja tener left join con join utilizando el where para vincularlas

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento       
LEFT JOIN 
    SIM_Equipamiento 
ON 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.idSIM=SIM_Equipamiento.idSIM
LEFT JOIN 
     Equipamiento_TipoTelefono
ON 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.tipoTelefono = Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.idTipo    
WHERE 
    Telefonia_Equipamiento.activo = 1 
    AND 
Equipamiento_TipoTelefono.descripcion='Empleados';
```

Comment: Funciona. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda